# Postgresql remove duplicates from table in process of retrieval based on criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a business logic where I want to retrieve translations from the database, The translations can be overridden so overridden translations should be retrieved when available.

```
Schema:

i18n
-----
id
slug // unique

i18nTranslations
--------------
id
i18nId              // referencing i18n.id
langId
text    
overriddenType     // pageOverride / instanceOverride

i18nPageOverrides
-----------------
id
translationId      // referencing i18nTranslations.id
instanceId
pageId
```

```
Example:

i18nTranslations                    
------------------------------------------------------
id  i18nId  langId   text       type     overrideType
------------------------------------------------------  
1 | ABC    | En    | AAX      | static  |   
2 | ABC    | En    | AAX Ovd  | static  | pageOverride  
3 | ABC    | Tr    | TDF      | static  |   
                        
                        
i18nPageOverride    
--------------------------          
transId pageId  instanceId  
--------------------------  
2       login   admin
```

```
Expected Output:
            
------------------------------------------------------
id  i18nId  langId   text       type     overrideType
------------------------------------------------------  
2 | ABC    | En    | AAX Ovd  | static  | pageOverride  // overridden data
3 | ABC    | Tr    | TDF      | static  |
```

In the expected output above, The row with "**AAX**" text has been eliminated since it had overridden row for the lang.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior just by using a query?

Comment: What is the unique thing about row with id 1 which allows 2 to override it? What if 3 had "TDF Ovd", would that be a separate entry or override the AAX? If separate, is `text` on its own the "unique" field you want to get the override for, or is it a combination of `langId` and `text`, or more? This is definitely doable in a single query (first thing that comes to mind is `DISTINCT ON`), but you'd need to know exactly how to group together distinct "entities", if you will, in order to then know which version of that entity you want.

Comment: Basically, I have a business logic where we have default translations for all the app, and each text on each page have an association with these translations, and then we've got a feature to override translation for page level, so if we are visiting on let's say page1 that has a text "AAX" we can override that text and then overridden entries will also be inserted in the i18nTranslations table with type "pageOverride" and another entry in i18nPageOverride table will also be inserted, which you can see from the example above. You can see the full schema here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cddf6/9/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) expression with an `ORDER BY` could be perfect for this.

The sorting can be on a descending i18nPageOverrides.id, with the nulls sorted last.

> DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each
> set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
> DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
> ORDER BY (see above).

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT ON (tr.i18nId, tr.langId) 
>  tr.id, tr.i18nId, tr.langId, tr.itText, tr.itType, tr.overrideType
> FROM i18nTranslations tr
> LEFT JOIN i18nPageOverrides po ON po.translationId = tr.id
> ORDER BY tr.i18nId, tr.langId, po.id DESC NULLS LAST, tr.id;
> ```

> | id | i18nid | langid | ittext | ittype | overridetype |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | ABC | En | AAX Ovd | static | pageOverride |
> | 3 | ABC | Tr | TDF | static | *null* |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=191f314f92d9081ddfee7d3a0e6c3419)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` to make a row number for duplicate number then filter `rn = 1` rows.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "iId",
       "itI18nId",
        "itLangId",
        "itText",
        "itType",
        "itOverrideType"
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "itI18nId","itLangId" ORDER BY "itOverrideType","iCreatedAt") rn
  FROM i18n i 
  INNER JOIN i18n_translations t
  ON i."iId" = t."itI18nId"
  LEFT JOIN i18n_page_override o 
  ON o."ipoTranslationId" = t."itId"
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cddf6/24/0)**:

```
|                                  iId |                             itI18nId |                             itLangId | itText |       itType | itOverrideType |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|--------|--------------|----------------|
| b76481bc-1171-4fb3-8433-31302ae39a81 | b76481bc-1171-4fb3-8433-31302ae39a81 | 175376f6-9dc8-4bea-bbc0-bf93744999c9 |    Adi | staticNormal |         (null) |
| b76481bc-1171-4fb3-8433-31302ae39a81 | b76481bc-1171-4fb3-8433-31302ae39a81 | 875dbdbb-9cb2-4f1b-a8ca-096321a0cd36 | Fn Ovd | staticNormal | stPageOverride |
```